# Call the API using CLI PHP without waiting for a response

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface

I have one URL: http://192.168.10.136:81/print/in-bill-tmp.
Currently I'm calling it using laravel's HTTP but I need to wait for the response to do the next thing, which causes my processing to slow down a lot. So is there any way I can call it without waiting for a response, such as PHP CLI?

Please give me an example!

Comment: Can you call the script via CLI or do you need to call the URL?

Comment: @volkerschulz I need to call a url with an api key: X-Api-Key: 'abcdefgh'

Comment: I am doing the following:
$response = Http::timeout(60)->withHeaders([
                    'X-Api-Key' => config('crm_api.key')
                ])->get($apiUrl, $payload);

Comment: You could then add `ignore_user_abort(true)` to the API endpoint and in your calling script use the request pooling function with a ridiculously short timeout. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#concurrent-requests for details.

Comment: I want to use CLI! alternative to http above without having to wait for api response. Can you help me with an example? Thank you very much

Comment: What I just suggested would be without waiting for a response. Of course you could do the very same using CLI by calling curl or wget there.

Comment: For avoiding of waiting application to response, you should use queue jobs.

Comment: @Tpojka That's what I was trying to suggest. Laravel (Guzzle) it's called "pooling". But OP wants CLI! :P

Comment: @volkerschulz queue/jobs are environment independent, those can be used from client as well from console. In that action, console is also client that communicates with [server] application.

Answer (score 0):

Use an **AJAX** call to send the request back to the web server.

**Optionally check for success** -- in a "callback".  But if there is a failure, it gets clumsy as to where to inform the user that the "print" failed.

So, instead, you could simply **ignore the callback** from the AJAX call.

**Sample code**

```
<script>
function ajaxNoReply(url) {
    // AJAX - tell server to do something; ignore response
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?PHP
...
     $url = "http://192.168.10.136:81/print.php/in-bill-tmp";
     echo "<button onClick=ajaxNoReply('$url')>Print it</button>";
```

**No CLI**, but does involve having a PHP script to handle the request.  It *could* be the same script you are coming from, but then you need to check the arguments `$_GET`, etc, to see whether it is a regular request or an ajax call.

The technique returns "instantly"; all the work is in the background in another process; it can take as long as necessary.

**No queue**.  Still, do not spawn hundreds of such calls at once.  Anyway, how fast can a user press buttons?  Probably not as fast as they get finished.

Sorry, I can't transliterate this into Laravel.